# Double up bit gb-emu

Tags: emulation, gameboy

Apologies in advance as this is an old topic. I was reading the following post on how the Nintendo logo data is decompressed and scaled before being copied into the v-ram during bootstrap and interestingly enough the data written does indeed look gibberish (as pointed out by the questioner) and I have tried my best (with a gb emulator I wrote) to produce that same output...but without success.

[Link to post](https://www.reddit.com/r/EmuDev/comments/bh7xwj/gameboy_bootstrap_logo)

The assembly code in question is this part of the boot rom:

```
LD C,A      ; $0095  "Double up" all the bits of the graphics data
    LD B,$04        ; $0096     and store in Video RAM
Addr_0098:
    PUSH BC     ; $0098
    RL C            ; $0099
    RLA         ; $009b
    POP BC      ; $009c
    RL C            ; $009d
    RLA         ; $009f
    DEC B           ; $00a0
    JR NZ, Addr_0098    ; $00a1
    LD (HL+),A      ; $00a3
    INC HL      ; $00a4
    LD (HL+),A      ; $00a5
    INC HL      ; $00a6
    RET
```

In reply to above post the output to v-ram is show to be:

```
8000: 00000000000000000000000000000000
8010: F000F000FC00FC00FC00FC00F300F300
8020: 3C003C003C003C003C003C003C003C00
8030: F000F000F000F00000000000F300F300
8040: 000000000000000000000000CF00CF00
... and so on
```

Can anyone explain how this output is generated and if it is indeed correct?

Many thanks in advance.

P.S. Assumption is made that the Nintendo logo is explicitly (inside some C/Java code) copied over to v-ram starting at address `0104h` during boot process to test the bootstrap.

```
.DB $CE,$ED,$66,$66,$CC,$0D,$00,$0B,$03,$73,$00,$83,$00,$0C,$00,$0D 
.DB $00,$08,$11,$1F,$88,$89,$00,$0E,$DC,$CC,$6E,$E6,$DD,$DD,$D9,$99 
.DB $BB,$BB,$67,$63,$6E,$0E,$EC,$CC,$DD,$DC,$99,$9F,$BB,$B9,$33,$3E
```

Answer (score 1):

After going through my code and seeing a potential silly bug (maybe a couple or two) I was able to finally get the same result as above. Please consider this resolved.

Basically I was forgetting to update the F register after the settings were changed for INC n, Add n and Sub n.

So technically, the above output seems to be correct.